# rsync functions in .bashrc not working in shell

Tags: bash, function, rsync

I have the following functions in my .bashrc file:

```
# functions
    # rsync transfer for DAMS uploads
function rsyncDAMS () {
    rsync -avvPhi --no-p
}
export -f rsyncDAMS

    # general rsync transfer
function rsyncT () {
    rsync -avvPhi
}
export -f rsyncT

    # general rsync transfer with deletion of source files
function rsyncD () {
    rsync -avvPhi --remove-source-files
}
export -f rsyncD
```

but either of the three I run just brings up the rsync help page. I used to have them as aliases and everything worked fine. I wanted to make them functions in .bashrc so I could use some of the advantages inherent in that. But, I am unclear why this is not working.

Comment: There is almost certainly no need to export them. The only thing that would use them would be other `bash` scripts, and you rarely want a shell script to depend on any particular user's environment.

Comment: Yes, I want to be able to use them in other bash scripts that I write specifically for this computer. @chepner

Comment: It would be better to define them directly in the script, or in a separate file that is explicitly sourced by your script.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the argument to `rsync`. It can be done using something like this:

```
function rsyncDAMS () {
    rsync -avvPhi --no-p "$@"
}
```

Comment: I added that in but it is still bringing up the rsync help page when I type the function. @Jakuje

Comment: So add `set -x` before calling your function and update the question with the output.

Comment: `/Users/medialab
≈:≈ set -x rsyncT
+ set -x rsyncT
++ print_before_the_prompt
++ printf '\n\e[1;93m%s\n\e[0m' /Users/medialab
`

Comment: Are you running the script from a login shell? `.bashrc` is not sourced, unless you do so explicitly from `.bash_profile` (or whatever file your login shell sources on startup).

Comment: my .bash_profile reads `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi`